# Bolt CMS - Identifier "rootpath" is not defined

Tags: php, bolt-cms

After moving a working bolt installation from my local machine to another server, I keep getting errors, no matter what I do.

Moving was done via copying all but contents of `files`, `vendor` and `app/cache` folders and then running `composer update` which was completed successfully.

When I run anything, for example `php app/nut`, I get this exception:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'InvalidArgumentException' with message 
   'Identifier "rootpath" is not defined.' 
   in xxxxxx/vendor/pimple/pimple/lib/Pimple.php:78
```

It's a **bolt 1.6** installation. Initially installed from the complete zip file from their website and then "converted" to the composer installed version. Still working perfectly on my system.

The new server with the error is running linux with apache 2.4 and PHP 5.4.34.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just covering off the discussion on IRC for anyone that hits this same problem.

Bolt docs are currently needing update as the master branch is what is about to be released as version 2, so copying 1.x files will void warranty.

A workaround is to `git pull --all` and then `git checkout release/1.6` to get the 1.x branch.

Comment: On a sidenote, if you are missing your thumbnails after the upgrade, you need to install the `fileinfo` extension. It's needed by the new thumbnail generator.